# BASH - ignore hidden files and empty source directory when copying

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

I'm new to BASH, and I've been working with this script with cron job. I had some trouble with it, originally using `mv`, but it turns out it won't merge with matching directories, or anything. So I was advised to use `cp`, since that supposedly will merge and replace.

/schedule/    = source directory
/public_html/ = target directory

```
#!/bin/bash

[ignore dot files/hidden files when copying]
cp -a schedule/* public_html/
[empty contents of source directory(schedule/) after copying]
```

Source: `/schedule/` (containing folders/files)

```
/files/
--4.html
--5.html
/assets/
--sitemap.xml
```

Destination: `/public_html/` (previous folders already exist)

```
/files/
--1.html
--2.html
--3.html
/assets/
--sitemap.xml
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to find out how to ignore hidden files while using `cp`, and to empty source directory after copying. I was reading the BASH reference manual and saw `nullglob`, but I don't know if that's what should be used.

Could anyone provide an example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, `rsync` has a `--exclude` option which can filter hidden files out and a `--prune-empty-dirs` option which can filter empty dirs out.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use following `find command` to list all files that are not hidden and directories that are not empty:**

```
find /schedule -not -path '*/\.*' -not -empty
```

Now for adding `cp`:

```
find /schedule -not -path '*/\.*' -not -empty -exec cp -a '{}' /public_html/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

With your command `cp -a schedule/* public_html/` you have already accomplished the first part of your task [ignore dot files when copying], since pathname expansion ignores file names beginning with a ''.'' if the **GLOBIGNORE** variable and the **dotglob** option are not set - you can `unset GLOBIGNORE` to ensure this.

For the second part [to empty the source directory after copying] just append the `rm` command:

```
cp -a schedule/* public_html && rm -r schedule/*
```

or

```
cp -a schedule/* public_html && rm -r schedule/{,.[!.]}*
```

(if you want dot files to be removed as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to catch all the hidden files and folders and negate this with `!`. You can then list all `FILES` and copy and remove the files.

```
FILES=$(find /PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f ) 
for f in $FILES; 
do 
 cp /PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER/$f /PATH/TO/DEST/FOLDER/$f;
 rm /PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER/$f
done
```

Alternatively you could use `mv` instead of `cp` and `rm`.

Comment: Capturing file names into a string has the well-docucented problem that it won't work correctly with file names which contain shell metaoharacters. You can use an array instead but it's still tricky to get right. I would probably go with `find ... -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" /path/to/dest/ || rm "$@"' _ {} +` though this depends on `find` with support for `+` with `-exec`